# How to store listed values from a database to variables in Anylogic 8.7.1?

Tags: java, anylogic

I am creating an agent based model in Anylogic 8.7. There is a point that I want to use query to get a List of values from a database table(rs_table) with a condition, here is the Java code that anylogic writes at the designated place:

`(int) selectFrom(rs_table) .where(rs_table.tr.eq(1)) .list(rs_table.impact)`

but I do not know how to store those values and how to reach them one by one. I would be grateful if you help me out thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a collection. Add a collection element from the "Agent" Pallet. The collection should have the following properties:

- Collection Class: LinkedList
- Element Class: Int

Use the following code:

```
collection.addAll(
selectFrom(rs_table) .where(rs_table.tr.eq(1)) .list(rs_table.impact)
);
```

Now, you can access the value from the collection as follows:

```
collection.get(i);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response it helped me through that process but now I want to make this query dynamic by using a variable as a condition for example:

collection.addAll(
selectFrom(rs_table) .where(rs_table.tr.eq(Tr)) .list(rs_table.impact)
);

I used 'Tr' variable as a condition for the query but now I am getting a Nullpointer exception at model run. Is it possible to embed this dynamic feature into the query?

Answer (score 0):

The "Iterate over returned rows and do something" option of the Insert Database Query wizard is precisely designed for this. It produces query code that loops through the returned list and prints each column's value to the console (via a `traceln` call); you just replace the code within the loop with what you actually want to do for each returned row (where the template code shows you how to get the value of each column in the row).

The wizard (if you use the QueryDSL form) will produce code like below:

```
List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(rs_table)
    .where(rs_table.tr.eq(1))
    .list();

for (Tuple row : rows) {
    traceln(
        row.get( rs_table.tr ) + "\t" + 
        row.get( rs_table.impact )
    );
}
```

(with extra `row.get` lines for any other table columns beyond the `tr` and `impact` ones).

(In Java terms, the query's `list` function returns a `List` of `Tuple` objects as the code shows.)